# uploading non-ascii characters from memory to bucket causes garbled text

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code:

```js
const uploadToGCS = async (destFileName, html, objectPrefix) => {
  const storage = new Storage()
  try {
    await storage
      .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
      .file(destFileName)
      .save(Buffer.from(html, "utf-8"))
    console.log(`uploaded ${destFileName} to ${BUCKET_NAME}.`)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

When my file contents contain non-ascii characters (Japanese characters), the uploaded object on GCS is garbled. I tried to change content-encoding metadata but it does nothing.

Comment: when I set Content-Type metadata to `binary/octet-stream`, then the downloaded file is not garbled